# Css File seems to get overwritten with jquery mobile css file

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey guys im having a really frustrating moment with CSS and jquery at the moment, basically i havent been doing much web development and only just really getting back into it.

So right now im trying to implement a side menu that pops out from the side ie. like mobile site however everytime i add the location jquery.mobile.min.css file to my document it completely overwrites my index.css which is holding my background image, font color, font size etc. screenshot of what problem is as shown below:

http://gyazo.com/cbde0a82cd06c981b02d99652d5fb770

below is how im layering out my links and scripts as ive heard putting scripts at the bottom is better:

```
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
```

however i did get the side menu to work albeit without my css working, i got that going for me which is nice

Answer (score 1):

You should load your personal stylesheets after your frameworks / themes if you want their styles to take precedence.

Example:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file2.css">
    ...
</head>
```

file1.css:

```
.class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

file2.css:

```
.class {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The `background-color` will be computed as `blue` because it comes later, thus has a higher priority. This is known as [Rule Order priority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_Priority_scheme_.28highest_to_lowest.29).